# Excel VBA SeriesCollection two series with different xvalue scales

Tags: excel, vba

I try to plot two graphs in one diagram from vba in excel. One has discrete x range from -10 to 10, the otherone is the approximated "continuous" gaussian distribution scaling from -10 to 10 with stepwide 0.1.

```
 Dim xvalue_norm(201) As Double
 Dim NormFassung(201) As Double
 Dim c As Integer

 For i = 1 To 20
    For j = 1 To 10
        c = c + 1               
        xvalue_norm(c) = i - 11 + (j - 1) / 10 '(-10,-9.9,-9.8,...,10)
        NormFassung(c) = WorksheetFunction.NormDist(i - 11 + (j - 1) / 10, mean_fassung, sigma_fassung, False)
    Next j
 Next i

Dim xvalue_hist(21) As Double
Dim HistFassung(21) As Double

For i = 1 To 21
    xvalue_hist(i) = (i - 11) '(-10,-9,-8,...,10)
    HistFassung(i) = Fassung(i) / summe_fassung
Next i


 ActiveSheet.Shapes.AddChart.Select
 ActiveChart.ChartType = xlLine 
 ActiveChart.Location Where:=xlLocationAsNewSheet     
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MinimumScale = 0
 ActiveChart.Axes(xlValue).MaximumScale = 0.5

    'Series 1 :
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Name = "NormVert"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).XValues = xvalue_norm
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(1).Values = NormFassung

    'Series 2 :
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Name = "Historie"
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).XValues = xvalue_hist
    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection(2).Values = HistFassung
```

The diagram is initialized correctly with the right xvalue range from -10 to 10 and the first Series is plotted well, but the xvalues of Series 2 "Historie" seems to use the the range (-10,-9.9,-9.8,...,-8) instead of the discrete values (-10,-9,-8,...,10).

Comment: Did you try adding different x axes using just the chart wizard? I'm not sure whether defining different XValues is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but the following symbols are not defined so the code does not compile.

```
i , j, mean_fassung, sigma_fassung, summe_fassung
```

Difficult to progress.